# How can I scale font size of text to fit inside a div that also scales when the browser window is resized?

Tags: css, text, fonts, resize, scale

Hello I am fairly new to all of this. I have built my layout using divs that have their dimensions set as percentages so that they scale to the correct size when the browser window is resized. Some of the divs form buttons in a navigation bar (with text on each). But when I resize the browser window the text stays large. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Is it only the buttons' text that you need reduced? Or the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
iStandardWidth = 960;
topofthetopdiv.style.zoom = parseInt(window.innerWidth/iStandardWidth, 10);
```

Comment: errm. thankyou for the quick response :) but where abouts to i put this, and which bits do I change? thanks

Comment: you have to decide and setup your standard size first: the size of browser that you want to be the size when everything shows 100%.

then change "topofthediv" by your top parent div javascript object name...

Comment: ok well i changed "topofthediv" to the parent div's class name.. Sorry to be such a noob but do I enclose this in <script type="text/javascript></script> tags? That's what I have done at the moment.. the script is in the body. It's not working at the moment.

Comment: yes this code is javascript, but it should be your window.onresize event so it actually takes in consideration updated browser size.
there's something else, zoom is css3, maybe your browser doesn't support it.

Comment: So I have to create a style class called .zoom? I really have no knowledge of javascript. So would it be like this? <script type="text/javascript>
$(document.window).onresize(function() { or something I dont know? :(

Comment: no, zoom is a css property already, not a class. For the rest I don't use jquery so i can't really help your syntax... sorry